# printing invoices

Tags: c#, reporting

I have invoice data stored in SQL now I want  to print those invoices, It would probably take me less than an hour to print them manually but that is  not the point I want to do it programmatically  using c# What is the quickest simplest way? Excel? Links to some examples?
TIA
Stuart

Comment: 1. What is your current programming knowledge? (How many years? What language(s)?)
2. What is the actual database backend? (Microsoft SQL Server? MySQL? PostgreSQL Oracle?)
3. What type of document are you attempting to generate? (HTML? PDF?)

Comment: i saw that you have added a tag for telerik reporting, so are you already using it ? are you asking about is it good or not? if so then the answer is yes, it's pretty cool tool to generate reports and it will give you the ability to export the report into many formats(image - pdf - word - etc) so give more details

Comment: @Amgad The tag is simply 'reporting'. The telerik picture is an advertisement imposed by SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Crystal Reports to print the invoices in C#.